# A summary of all Jakarta EE Specifications

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-8

For All Java EE 8 specifications Oracle has a page https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-ee-glance.html#javaee8 .

This gives us around 40 API spec's . Where Can I find a similar spec for Jakarta EE 8 . In its website around 31 are listed.. But some other API's like SAAJ etc are not mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

I think SAAJ is called now "Jakarta SOAP Attachments" the specification can be found in the website

https://jakarta.ee/specifications/